# Using API in partial and passing values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, parameter-passing, partials

I am trying to display some info from an API.

I have this code:

```
<% recco = Model.find_by_id(activity.trackable.id %>
```

Now, rendering the following line will output the ID I want:

```
<%= recco.item_id %>
```

However, when I want to link to this item and I need the name from the API, some of the code fails and some not. This is the line I have:

```
<%= link_to @client.author(recco.item_id).name, book_path(recco.item_id) %>
```

The `book_path` works and displays a link to the correct URL with the ID. The client that tries to get the name from the API returns that it is not found.

But, if I try remove the the `recco.item_id` and just hardcode it to:

```
<%= link_to @client.author("7").name, book_path(recco.item_id) %>
```

It works and displays the author name. Is there a special reason for the API request to not understand that the `recco.item_id` is a number? The `book_path` displays the link just fine.

Comment: what is the @client stands for, what is the definition of author method

Comment: The @client is for goodreads api: `@client = Goodreads.new(Goodreads.configuration)`

Comment: Are you using the gem from here, https://github.com/sosedoff/goodreads. It used RestClient underground to do the http request, so i don't think whether the passed in id is a string or is a number will meter to this issue. Maybe the author you query just doesn't exists. Have you output the value of recco.item_id, and see whether is really exists on goodreads.

Comment: Yes, by passing the value "7" as I mentioned returns the author name as expected from the goodreads api. But when passing recco.item_id (which is 7 in this case) does only return Goodreads::NotFound

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the `author` method expects a string instead of an integer. All you have to do is add `to_s` to the item_id for it to work:

```
<%= link_to @client.author(recco.item_id.to_s).name, book_path(recco.item_id) %>
```

The reason why the API does not understand the integer you passed to it is likely because they did not logic have in that method to convert that passed argument into a string. Ideally, a public would try and convert whatever args are passed to it into the type of value it expects. The `to_s` we did on your method would ideally be in the API, but since you likely don't have control over the API code, you'll have to do the workaround yourself which doesn't take much effort anyway. :)

Comment: That did not works. This is a partial for public_activity (_create.html.erb) The code with the recco.item_id works in the normal view, but for some reason not here.

Comment: I have also tried `@client.author(#{recco.item_id}).name` and combination of `aut = recco.item_id.to_s` and the `@client.author(aut).name`. None works, but they all **do** once I just enter a number (ex: 7) manually into the code.

Comment: When it works by providing a number as an argument, is the number you provided a String or an Integer? Is the partial for the same action as where the view works?

Comment: integer. In the view for the author show page I use params[:id] instead of the recco.item_id. But the rest is the same.

Comment: Then what is the output of params[:id] and recco.item_id? If recco.item_id is returning a String, then that is likely your problem and you could try doing `recco.item_id.to_i`.